# Bytes variables are connected

Tags: solidity, arrays, bytes, storage-pointer

Why are these variables confounding? The returned result shows that both loops are effecting both bytes variables (`second` returns the same result).

```
function mix() public returns (bytes) {  

    bytes first;
    for (uint8 cnt = 0; cnt<8; cnt++) {
        first.push(9)
    }


    bytes second;
    for (uint8 cnt2 = 0; cnt2<8; cnt2++) {
        second.push(8);
    }

    return first;
}
```

Returned result:
`'0x09090909090909090808080808080808'`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is going to take a few hops to explain.

The code looks innocent enough, but there is a compiler warning about uninitialized storage pointers. The warning shouldn't be ignored.

Written explicitly, it would be

`bytes storage first;`

Storage pointers can start to look like slight of hand. Consider this:

```
MyStruct s = structsMap[key];
s.someVal = false;
```

The storage at `structsMap[key]` will be set to `false` because `s` is a storage pointer (a.k.a. reference variable). Instead of holding the value, it holds a pointer to storage. When you write to `s`, you are writing to the actual storage at whatever slot `s` refers to, which it got when it was initialized.

Your `bytes first;` statement doesn't have anything on the right (of `=`), so it's not initialized, so it gets the *default* of slot `0`. That's the "uninitialized" part of the warning. `bytes second` gets the same slot `0`. Yikes! Now we have things that look separate stomping on the same storage slot. **Here be dragons.**

If we declare the storage in the global section, it will work as expected:

```
contract NoMixing {

    bytes public first;
    bytes public second;

    function mix() public returns (bytes, bytes) {  

        for (uint8 cnt = 0; cnt<8; cnt++) {
            first.push(9);
        }

        for (uint8 cnt2 = 0; cnt2<8; cnt2++) {
            second.push(8);
        }

        return (first,second);
    }

}
```

I'm not a huge fan of storage pointers because code like yours looks like it should work. See this: https://vessenes.com/solidity-frustrations-references-and-mapping/

Some general safety tips:

1. Declare storage outside functions.
2. Use `memory` explicitly when assigning something from an indexed type (`[]`). It would make your `push` method fail but at least you'd be alerted to the issue.
3. Use extreme caution with `x` after `x = somethingInStorage[index];` so you don't overwrite something you didn't mean to alter.

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE**

This is such an interesting example, I decided to blog about the issue. Here's an explainer about storage pointers in Solidity with some safety suggestions for avoiding this sort of confusion: https://blog.b9lab.com/storage-pointers-in-solidity-7dcfaa536089

Comment: I wonder if this is solved in later versions of Solidity

Comment: It is. You can't declare a storage variable inside a function.